# SUBSTRING a filename in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, substring, filenames

I need help to make a batch code (if it's possible) to get substring from filename.
My filename can be like (filename lenght is changing):

```
7_D_D1_012345678-2015-07-07.pdf
8_A_087654321-2015-07-07.pdf
10_D_D1_011122558-2015-07-07.pdf
100_C_CCC1_C2_C3_C4_055555555-2015-07-07.pdf
```

file number - from left to first `_`

id1 - from 1 to n string with _ separator; for example `C_C1_C2_C3_C4`

id2 - always 9 digits; `for example 011122558`

date - for example `2015-07-07`

extension `.jpg`

How to loop substring (file number, id1, d2, date) for all filenames in folder and put it to my code

```
convert - "file number" -annotate "id1" -annotate2 "id2" -annotate "date"
```

for example:

```
convert - "01" -annotate "C_C1" -annotate2 "012345678" -annotate "2015-07-07"
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: In all honesty, I would not do this in a batch file. I would do `dir folder >tmp.cmd`, then use a text editor that has regular expression replacement capability (vim, emacs, Notepad Plus) to turn the filenames into the desired commands.

Comment: I need a tool to automatically generate code and run it. Maybe ther is an other way than use text editors.

Comment: I suppose `sed` (or `awk`, or `perl`) could do the trick. What do you have available? Are you open to downloading some tools, or does it have to be straight batch?  What about Powershell?

Comment: I don't have any, but I can download something i you give me advice. I need a tool which will run under WIN 7 without administartor privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pure batch. Simple string manipulation mixed with tokenization. No need for additional utilities.

(`g.txt` holds your example file names; could be replaced by `'dir /b /a-d'`)

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (g.txt) do call :process %%i
goto :eof

:process
set x=%1
set ext=%x:*.=%
for /f "delims=_" %%i in ("%x%") do set fileno=%%i
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=-" %%i in ("%x%") do (
  set x1=%%i
  set x2=%%j
)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=." %%i in ("%x2%") do (
  set dat=%%i
  set ext=%%j
)
set id2=%x1:~-9%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%i in ("%x1:~0,-10%") do set id1=%%j
echo filename   %x%
echo ------------------------
echo    Nr. %fileno%
echo    ID1 %id1%
echo    ID2 %id2%
echo    Date    %dat%
echo    Ext.    %ext%
echo ------------------------
echo convert - "%fileno%" -annotate "%id1%" -annotate2 "%id2% -annotate "%dat%"
echo(
echo(
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, now I'm using WIN XP and it doesn't work (I can't see what is because cmd is closing so fast and I cant pause) - I'll try it later on WIN7.

Comment: no reason, why it shouldn't run on XP. Start it from a CMD-window and/or add a `pause` before the first `goto: eof` (third line).

Comment: Dammit. I forgot about the `tokens` and `delims` options.

Comment: WORKS GREAT.Thank you very much !
By the way, is it possible to read from g.txt if I'll put there full path to file, for example "C:\Test\7_D_D1_012345678-2015-07-07.pdf" etc.

Comment: possible with minor changes. But how does `convert` take paths? Or would you only give files with pathnames but process the filename only?

Comment: Files can be in subdirectories and did not know how to generate g.txt but now I know.Your code was very helpfull. You were the first and I give you "V" and great thanks to MC ND.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said Windows 7, I know you have Powershell available. Here is a Powershell script:

```
$re = '^(\d+)_((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_?)+)_(\d{9})-(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\.(\w+)$'
dir | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $re, 'convert "$1" -annotate "$2" -annotate2 "$3" -annotate3 "-$4"'}
```

Given the filenames you gave in your question

```
7_D_D1_012345678-2015-07-07.pdf
8_A_087654321-2015-07-07.pdf
10_D_D1_011122558-2015-07-07.pdf
100_C_CCC1_C2_C3_C4_055555555-2015-07-07.pdf
```

It will produce this text output:

```
convert "100" -annotate "C_CCC1_C2_C3_C4" -annotate2 "055555555" -annotate4 "2015-07-07"
convert "10" -annotate "D_D1" -annotate2 "011122558" -annotate4 "2015-07-07"
convert "7" -annotate "D_D1" -annotate2 "012345678" -annotate4 "2015-07-07"
convert "8" -annotate "A" -annotate2 "087654321" -annotate4 "2015-07-07"
```

(The filenames were sorted first, so the one starting with 100 comes first and the one starting with 8 comes last).

By redirecting this text output into a .cmd file, you can execute the convert commands as desired.

Here is the breakdown of that regular expression:

```
Beginning of line or string
[1]: A numbered capture group. [\d+]
    Any digit, one or more repetitions
_
[2]: A numbered capture group. [(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_?)+]
    Match expression but don't capture it. [(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_?], one or more repetitions
        (?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_?
            Match expression but don't capture it. [[a-zA-Z0-9]+]
                Any character in this class: [a-zA-Z0-9], one or more repetitions
            _, zero or one repetitions
_
[3]: A numbered capture group. [\d{9}]
    Any digit, exactly 9 repetitions
-
[4]: A numbered capture group. [\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d]
    \d{4}-\d\d-\d\d
        Any digit, exactly 4 repetitions
```

Comment: Can't believe I spent so long on this and now it isn't even the easiest answer.

Comment: Thanks for your job! I'll try it on my WIN 7 machine later.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem For each file
    for /r "x:\starting\folder" %%z in (*.pdf) do (
        rem Separate number part
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nz") do (
            set "_number=%%~a"
            set "_file=%%~fz"

            rem Separate date and ids 
            for /f "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%c in ("%%~b") do (
                set "_date=%%~d"
                set "_ids=%%~c\."
            )
        )   

        rem Separate id1 from id2 handling the string as a path
        rem This way id2 is the last element and the path to it 
        rem is id1
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%e in ("::!_ids:_=\!") do (
            endlocal
            set "_id2=%%~nxe"
            set "_id1=%%~pe"
        )

        rem Correct id1 contents (it is a path) changing backslashes 
        rem to underscores. As there are initial and ending backslashes,
        rem later we will remove the initial and ending underscores
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%e in ("!_id1:\=_!") do (
            endlocal
            set "_id1=%%~e"
        )

        rem Execute final command 
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(
        echo file[!_file!] 
        echo convert - "!_number!" -annotate "!_id1:~1,-1!" -annotate2 "!_id2!" -annotate "!_date!"
        endlocal

    )
```

Comment: This code works too ! Thanks for good job. And what do you think about, is it possible to read .pdf from subfolders ? Subfolders are named - ID2.

Comment: @Artec, answer updated. Just added the `/r "path"` to the `for` recursive file search, and changed the line that retrieves the file name to `%%~fz` to get the full path to the file.

Comment: Thanks one more time.  Works great.